Date Object dont recognize a string using XLSX
I'm using XLSX package to read an excel file and for some reason some Date Objects are Date and others are string.
I'm using this line to define cells as Date type.
const workbook = XLSX.read(buff, {cellDates: true, dateNF:"dd/mm/yy"});

When is time to read this date "26/07/2024 00:00:00" I get undefined in this sentence
const dateToParse = new Date(dato);


I change this sentence const workbook = XLSX.read(buff, {cellDates: true, dateNF:"dd/mm/yy"}); and added another format "dd/mmmm/yyyy hh:ss:MMMM". That worked.
